# vba combine a few lines in one cell

Tags: vba

I have a three columns in excel with data such as

```
section1     section2     section3     
 no             no          er3       
 er1            no          er3    
 no             no          no
```

how to write macros to Combine the data in the on column such as:

```
section_error    
    er3        
    er1,er3        
    no
```

So if there are only "no" then it should be once "no"
if there is something else besides "no", like "er1"or "er3" then only list of others signs. 
it is not exactly to join or to CONCATENATE (

Answer (score 0):

Here's a macro solution, just looping through the rows/columns:

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim mystring As String

lastrow = Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Cells(Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    For j = 1 To 3
        If InStr(Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Cells(i, j).Value, "er") > 0 Then
            If mystring = "" Then
                mystring = Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Cells(i, j).Value
            Else
                mystring = mystring & "," & Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Cells(i, j).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next j

    If mystring <> "" Then
        Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Cells(i, 4).Value = mystring
        mystring = ""
    Else
        Worksheets("ICS Analysis").Cells(i, 4).Value = "no"
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

[image: img1]

Comment: I try to run this macro through Start button, I assigned macro to the button but it does not operate, while from module window by clicing "Run" it operates perfect.  What can be a reason?

Comment: @Elena What page is the button on? This macros run off the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: button is on the page "Main", but i created a Sub, for all Subs under start button

Comment: I rewrote macro:

Comment: Yes, I changed " lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row to  lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count " and it resolved the Problem:)

Comment: @Elena What page is your data on, "ICS Analysis"?

Comment: @Elena Check the edit - I made it a static solution for your worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

So, this might be a bit overkill depending on how many rows you have. But, using arrays is going to be a lot faster if you start getting up in the thousands.

Anyway, we define two named ranges, input and output. We then place the values of the input range into an array.

We loop through the array, checking the values of those spots in the array (which corresponds to the values in the cells now). When we find something, we append that something to the end of our output value for that row. When we don't find anything, we set that value to no.

At the end, we set the values of the output range (resized for our array) equal to our output array values.

Make sure you define those named ranges (and change their names too!).

Let me know if you have questions.

```
Option Explicit

Sub combineColumns()
    Dim combineRange As Range, pasteRange As Range
    Dim inputArr() As Variant, outputArr() As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, numberOfRows As Long
    Dim currentOutputvalue As String

    'Named range with values to combine, don't include header
    Set combineRange = Range("yourNamedRangeToCombineHere")
    'only need to set the top of the range to paste
    Set pasteRange = Range("theCellAtTheTopOfWhereYouWantToPaste")

    'put the values of the range you want to combine into the input array
    inputArr = combineRange.Value2

    'find the size of the array
    numberOfRows = UBound(inputArr, 1)

    'dimension the output array, same number of rows, but only one column
    ReDim outputArr(1 To numberOfRows, 1 To 1)

    'loop through our rows
    For i = 1 To numberOfRows

        'set the current output value to a blank
        currentOutputvalue = ""

        'loop through our three columns
        For j = 1 To 3
            'if cell value is not no, append the value to the end of current output value
            'also append a comma
            If inputArr(i, j) <> "no" Then
                currentOutputvalue = currentOutputvalue & inputArr(i, j) & ","
            End If
        Next

        If currentOutputvalue = "" Then
            'all columns in this row were "no", so change value to "no"
            currentOutputvalue = "no"
        Else
            'there was at least one not no
            'trim off the end comma
            currentOutputvalue = Left(currentOutputvalue, Len(currentOutputvalue) - 1)
        End If

        'assign the value to the spot in the array
        outputArr(i, 1) = currentOutputvalue
    Next

    'resize the pasterange to the size of the array, and
    'set the values of the range to those in the output array
    pasteRange.Resize(numberOfRows, 1).Value2 = outputArr

End Sub
```

Comment: @dwirony. 's solution is good too. And probably easier to maintain/follow if you're not as familiar to VBA, because arrays can be a bit tricky. His also has the advantage of not needing to create those named ranges.

Comment: Thank you very much, all answers are  very helpful!